# Why counter_cache doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I used counter_cache to count the User's posts number, but it doesn't work.

```
#Post Model    
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end

#User Model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

There are a Posts Table and also a posts_count in my Users Table

When I create a new post,the posts_count can't count the number,just stop 0.Very strange problem.What am I missing?

--------------------More detail------------------

I track the create action:

```
User Load (0.0ms) SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
SQL (7.0ms) describe `posts`AREL (0.0ms)INSERT INTO `posts` (`user_id`, `title`, `content`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, 'test', 'test','2011-06-01 07:29:10', '2011-06-01 07:29:10')
SQL (54.0ms) COMMIT
SQL (0.0ms) BEGIN
AREL (1.0ms)UPDATE `posts` SET `user_id` = 1, `updated_at` = '2011-06-01 07:29:10' WHERE `posts`.`id` = 16[0m
SQL (38.0ms) COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/user/post
Completed 302 Found in 250ms
```

---------------------OK now---------------------

In my Post Creat Action:

```
#I change the following code 
#@post = Post.create(params[:post])
#@user.posts << @post

@post = @user.posts.build(params[:post])
@post.save
```

Comment: How are you creating the post? Any errors? Does the post actually save?

Comment: I create the post by the Create Action @post.save,it create successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that save and create are different, in the same respect as destroy and delete.

Save and delete won't go through any callbacks, so it won't update the cache counter. You should use create, if you want to update the cache counter.

Comment: I used @post = Post.create(params[:post]),but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked your database, and verified that the entry has indeed been saved?

Comment: Yes,I think maybe I have made some silly mistakes,but I can't find it.

Comment: Maybe I should track the create action.